# How one can simplify this product of sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

My question is simple: How one can simplify this product of sums:

$$S=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\right)
    \left(\sum_{k=1}^{p}b_{k}\right)
    \left(\sum_{k=1}^{q}c_{k}\right)$$

where $a_{k},b_{k},c_{k}$ are real sequences and $n<p<q$.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify? I think that is as compact as things can get without knowing a,b,c. If you want to expand them you can assign different indices, but I wouldn't call that simpler!

Comment: Can you find an alternative expression simplier than $a(b_1+b_2)(c_1+c_2+c_3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have
$$
S=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\right)
  \left(\sum_{k=1}^{p}b_{k}\right)
  \left(\sum_{k=1}^{q}c_{k}\right)
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^p \sum_{k=1}^q a_i b_j c_k?
$$

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?
\begin{align*}
(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k})(\sum_{k=1}^{p}b_{k})(\sum_{k=1}^{q}c_{k}) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^q a_ib_jc_k.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is about all you can do with such general sequences.  It's frankly debatable which is "simpler".